# How to find Time complexity of the give relation?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

You are given functions f and g such that `f(n)=O(g(n))`.

Is **f(n)∗log<sub>2</sub>(f(n)c)=O(g(n)∗log<sub>2</sub>(g(n)))** ?

(Here c is some positive constant.)

You should assume that f and g are nondecreasing and always bigger than 1.

Can anyone please help me in this question?

Thanks in advance for the explanation.

Comment: Hint: recall the algebraic definition of Big-O.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing that `f(n) = O(g(n))` is knowing that `f(n) <= Dg(n)` for some positive constant `D` whenever `n` is large enough. In other words, there exists some `N` such that the previous inequality holds for all `n > N`.

Now, for `n > N`, we have

```
f(n)lg(f(n)c) <= Dg(n)lg(Dg(n)c)               ; lg is an increasing function
              <= Dg(n)lg(g(n)) + Dg(n)lg(cD)   ; lg(xy)=lg(x)+lg(y)
```

Now take a positive constant `E` such that `lg(cD)D <= Elg(g(1))`. We get

```
              <= Dg(n)lg(g(n)) + Eg(n)lg(g(1))
              <= Dg(n)lg(g(n)) + Eg(n)lg(g(n)) ; g is non-decreasing
              <= (D + E)g(n)lg(g(n))
               = O(g(n)lg(g(n)))               ; by definition
```